# can any one suggest me a way for normalizing data ?

Tags: statistics

I want to have my data in range of 0-1 .
I tried min-max function, decimal scaling but i need other techniques.
My data has variable range from 0 - 35000 .

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to just divide by $35\,000$ and call it a day?

Comment: it is same as min max function i already used it i want another technique.

Comment: Can you explain why you want another technique?

Comment: what are you trying to do with your normalized data?

Comment: i want to use that data in neural network classification

Answer (score 0):

For real valued data, try composing the data by the function $x\mapsto\mathrm e^x/(\mathrm e^x+1)$. For positive real valued data, try composing the data by the function $x\mapsto(\mathrm e^x-1)/(\mathrm e^x+1)$ or by the function $\tanh$.

Comment: using the above function gives only values in range between 0.5 and 1 but i want data in range of 0-1 ???

Comment: See Edit. You might have wanted to reach this conclusion by yourself.